# How to test if a backbone view listens to specific event correctly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, sinon, chai

I'm trying to test if a Backbone.js view is correctly listening for a specific event triggered by the router. The initialize method on the view I'm testing looks something like this:

```
initialize: function(options) {
  this.router = options.router; // pass router obj through args
  this.listenTo(this.router, 'login_manager:show', this.buildLoginPage); // not shown on this snippet, but defined later
}
```

When a route is matched on my router, I do the following:

```
showLogin: function() {
  this.trigger('login_manager:show');
}
```

This code works as expected on the browser, but the test I did for it doesn't pass. Here's the test I'm trying to do:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  this.router = new Backbone.Router();
  this.loginManager = new LoginManager({
    router: this.router
  });
});

afterEach(function() {
  this.loginManager = null;
  this.router = null;
});

it('listens to correct event', sinon.test(function() {
  var spy = sinon.spy(this.loginManager, 'buildLoginPage');
  this.loginManager.router.trigger('login_manager:show');
  expect(spy.called).to.be.true;
}));
```

I haven't been able to get this test to pass, so I was wondering if anyone could help me out?

Thanks,

Diego.

Comment: `listenTo()` stops working when you remove view, please check if you do remove it somewhere, and place listenTo inside `render()` instead of `initialize()`, also you could use `this.router.on()` instead to make sure it's working always.

Comment: I'm not removing the view anywhere. I do not want to test if the router fires an event, but rather if the view listens to it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help

```js
it('listens to correct event', () => {
  var stub = sinon.stub();
  Backbone.Events.listenTo(this.loginManager.router, 'login_manager:show', stub);
  this.loginManager.router.trigger('login_manager:show');
  stub.called.should.be.true;
});
```